# Data sent to c# schema and the data is not populated in the xml output

Tags: c#, .net

I have generated a c# schema using the xsd successfully and using that schema, input the data and generate an xml. for single dimensional arrays the data in input but it is not populated in the xml output.

### c# schema generated using xsd (below is a piece of code from a big chunk of codes)

```
private CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology[] topographySNOMEDPathologyField;

/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TopographySNOMEDPathology", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology[] TopographySNOMEDPathology
    {
        get
        {
            return this.topographySNOMEDPathologyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.topographySNOMEDPathologyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/COSDPathology-v8-1")]
    public partial class CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology : CV
    {
    }
```

The data to the above constructor is passed like this:

```
var TypesTopographySNOMEDPathology = new List<CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology>();

 var TopographySNOMEDPathology  = new CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology();

{
                TopographySNOMEDPathology.code = ds.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCounter]["CORE_PATHOLOGY_TOPOGRAPHY_SNOMED_PATHOLOGY"].ToString();

 }

 TypesTopographySNOMEDPathology.Add(TopographySNOMEDPathology);
```

I expect the output as other data items like for example

```
<PathologyObservationReportId extension="4638661" />
```

Comment: The code posted does specify anything about PathologyObservationReportId nor extension.  So it is impossible to help without more info.

Comment: Sorry, that is an example, but am expecting    TopographySNOMEDPathology code = "6000"

Comment: Thanks Vipul for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication122
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            dt.Columns.Add("CORE_PATHOLOGY_TOPOGRAPHY_SNOMED_PATHOLOGY", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "6000"});

            int iRowCounter = 0;


            CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology TopographySNOMEDPathology = new CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology()
            {
                TopographySNOMEDPathology  = new List<TopographySNOMEDPathology>() {
                    new TopographySNOMEDPathology() {   code = (string)ds.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCounter]["CORE_PATHOLOGY_TOPOGRAPHY_SNOMED_PATHOLOGY"] }
                }
            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, TopographySNOMEDPathology);

         }
    }

    [XmlRoot("CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology")]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(CV))]
    public partial class CoreCorePathologyTypeTopographySNOMEDPathology : CV
    {
        [XmlElement("TopographySNOMEDPathology")]
        public List<TopographySNOMEDPathology> TopographySNOMEDPathology { get; set; }
    }
    public class CV
    {
    }
    [XmlRoot("TopographySNOMEDPathology")]
    public class TopographySNOMEDPathology
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
    }




}
```